# Youtube Analytics API Demographic dimension "gender" shows on analytics dashboard but gives query invalid on API Explorer

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-analytics

I am currently working with the Youtube Analytics API,

So far i have been able to pull all the data that youtube has to offer except the gender/ageGroup dimensions the query fails everytime,

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/dimsmets/dims) point to examples to playbacklocation and not the demographic it's self.

I am using the [PHP Client Library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/),

== PHP ==

```
$analytics_gender = new Google_YouTubeAnalyticsService($client);

$optparam = array('dimensions' => 'gender');

$metrics= "views";

$analytics_demo_gender = $analytics_gender->reports->query("channel==".$channelId, "2012-08-14", "2013-05-30", $metrics, $optparam);
```

When i run this query i get an `error (400) The query is not supported.` even though it works just fine for all the other metrics and dimensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `gender` dimension can only be used with the metric `viewerPercentage` (and optionally with a country and/or video filter and with an additional `ageGroup` dimension, if you'd like). You can search the [relevant documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports) for "gender" to see the exact specifications.

[Here's an example](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query?ids=channel%253D%253DCHANNEL_ID&start-date=2013-07-01&end-date=2013-07-15&metrics=viewerPercentage&dimensions=gender) of a working report in the API Explorer. Authenticate, and replace `CHANNEL_ID` with the id of your channel.

Comment: Cheers for the support :D

Comment: I didnot get any response data even there was no error .Please do you have any ideas??

Comment: Relevant 2022 link: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/channel_reports

Answer (score 1):

It's simple to do this, please check below code snippet to find demographic and gender statics:

```
request.get({
    url:'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?key={Google Api Key}&ids=channel=={channelId}&dimensions=country&metrics=views&end-date={endDate}&start-date={startDate}',
    json:true,
    timeout: 10000,
    headers:{'Authorization':'Bearer '+accessToken}},
    function (err,r,result) {
        console.log(result)
});
```

If you need to find gender info below code snippet can be used:

```
request.get({
    url:'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?key={Google Api Key}&ids=channel=={channelId}&dimensions=gender&metrics=viewerPercentage&end-date={endDate}&start-date={startDate}',
    json:true,
    timeout: 10000,
    headers:{'Authorization':'Bearer '+accessToken}},
    function (err,r,result) {
        console.log(result)
});
```

If you need to find gender info along with ageGroup below code snippet can be used

```
request.get({
    url:'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?key={Google Api Key}&ids=channel=={channelId}&dimensions=gender,ageGroup&metrics=viewerPercentage&end-date={endDate}&start-date={startDate}',
    json:true,
    timeout: 10000,
    headers:{'Authorization':'Bearer '+accessToken}},
    function (err,r,result) {
        console.log(result)
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please use indentation instead of `<pre>` blocks: the latter don't provide syntax highlightning, like I did in the suggested edit. Best regards.